# google sign in .net mvc default application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-plus-signin

I am trying to add google sign in option in default .net mvc template project.
As per many tutorials I tried to add the option but after redirecting to google sign in page and signing in it return backs to the default login page of the template as if nothing happened.

Things I've done so far to achieve this much,

.NET FRAMEWORK 4.5.2
copied the project url (SSL disabled) and pasted in redirect url with "/signin-google" attached.
created Auth2.0 client Ids as per the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KouVf.png) attached,
pasted the ClientID and secret in
`app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions() { ClientId = "931587660641-s4smfbatgr1ufsq5u704qeigca22i8he.apps.googleusercontent.com", ClientSecret = "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" });`

after attempting a few more times I've discovered the google sign prompt page actually sign in on the[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysdLV.png) instead of the web app.

[editor-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Oq3.png)
Please help me find the solution and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved....!

Did just one thing to achieve this.

1. Set `SSL Enabled Status = True`.
2. Right Click the `Project` ,Go to `Properties`.
3. Copy the `SSL URL` in Project URL under `WEB` Tab and click on `Create Virtual Directory` Button next to it.
4. Open Google API Credential and paste the URL under `Authorized JavaScript origins` like this
   `https://localhost:48428`
5. Copy the same URL and Paste under 'Authorized redirect URIs' with `/signin-google` at the end, like this
   `https://localhost:48428/signin-google`
6. Copy `ClientID` and `Client Secret`.
7. Open Project , Go to `Startup.Auth.cs` under `App_Start` folder.
8. Uncommand the below code and Paste the copied codes here

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = "",
                ClientSecret = ""
            });
```

5. Save and run your application and it should work.